# sass mixin for linear-gradient, code explanation

Tags: sass

I found the following mixin on the web, but have forgotten where I found it.

```
@mixin linear-gradient($direction, $gradients...) {
  background-color: nth($gradients, 1);
  background-image: linear-gradient($direction, $gradients...);
}
```

and then be called upon in a class with:

```
.selector {
  @include linear-gradient(to right, magenta, red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple);
}
```

This works fine, my question is about the `background-color: nth($gradients, 1);`is this a index that starts with 1 and is it used as a color-start?
Can someone explain?

Thanks :)

Comment: nth(gradients,1) does gets the first element/value from the $gradients list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,nth(gradients,1) picks the first element from the gradients list

so it would background-color:magenta here

for more explanation [this](http://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, `nth($gradients, 1)` picks the first item from `$gradients` as [Sass lists are 1-indexed](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#nth-instance_method).

In this case background-color is set to the first colour from gradients. You can think of this as a fallback in case the user's browser doesn't support linear-gradients.